# cant find the right node value for my XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

im making a project that has to display xml data to my website but im stuck. I need to figure out how to display 'ows_Person' from the 'z:row'. i dont know how to define it in the [0].ChildNodes[0].nodeValue, i would appreciate some help.

Javascript code:

```
<script>
var xmlhttp, xmlDoc;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML=
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
</script>
```

XML Code:

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-
microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
<s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
<s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:CommandTimeout="30">
<s:AttributeType name="ows_Attachments" rs:name="Attachments" rs:number="1">
<s:datatype dt:type="boolean" dt:maxLength="1" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_LinkTitle" rs:name="Title" rs:number="2">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_Person" rs:name="Person" rs:number="3">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:lookup="true" dt:maxLength="512" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_ID" rs:name="ID" rs:number="4">
<s:datatype dt:type="i4" dt:maxLength="4" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_Modified" rs:name="Modified" rs:number="5">
<s:datatype dt:type="datetime" dt:maxLength="8" />
</s:AttributeType>
<s:AttributeType name="ows_DocIcon" rs:name="Type" rs:number="6">
<s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="512" />
</s:AttributeType>
</s:ElementType>
</s:Schema>
<rs:data>
<z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="Test" ows_Person="1257;#Stefan de 
Boer" ows_ID="1" ows_Modified="2017-11-15 15:00:22" />
<z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="testtesttesttest" 
ows_Person="1256;#Kevin" ows_ID="2" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 10:46:07" 
/>
<z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="nog een test" 
ows_Person="1258;#Naomi" ows_ID="3" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 
10:53:11" />
<z:row ows_Attachments="0" ows_LinkTitle="alweer een test" 
ows_Person="1257;#Stefan" ows_ID="4" ows_Modified="2017-11-16 
10:53:44" />
</rs:data>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with `getAttribute`:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0].getAttribute('ows_person')
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for your fast response!                                                         
I tried to use your code and its not working. its not throwing any errors or anything, it just does nothing. am i doing something else wrong?

Comment: Does the `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("z:row")[0]` contain first `z:row`? Check it with `console.log`

Comment: the console only returns this :                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                               '[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
(anonymous) @ xmlfiletest.html:14'